Definition of Effect Identifiability in 'On Pearl's Hierarchy and Foundations of Causal Inference'
You can find the afore-mentioned text here. I'm asking a clarification of Definition 17, which is as follows:

Definition 17 (Effect Identifiability) The causal effect of an action $do(X=x)$ on a set of variables $Y$ given a set of observations on variables $Z = z$, probability $P(Y | do(x), z)$ is said to be identifiable from $P$ and $G$ if for every two models $M^{(1)}$ and $M^{(2)}$ with causal diagram $G$, equality $P^{(1)}(v)=P^{(2)}(v)>0$ implies $P^{(1)}(Y | do(x), z) = P^{(2)}(Y | do(x), z)$.

I'm a bit caught off guard by the $P^{(1)}(v)=P^{(2)}(v)>0$ condition, does it really mean that if equal measure in any single event implies equal interventional probability, then the effect is identifiable? I'm confused, as I would think that $P^{(1)}(z)=P^{(2)}(z)>0$ would be a more reasonable requirement. I checked several different versions of the text and they all say the former.
Question: Can someone please verify if the definition is indeed correct in using any event $v$ instead of $z$? If possible I would also appreciate an intuitive reasoning as to why equality in any event is enough, instead of equality on $P^{(1)}(z)=P^{(2)}(z)>0$ as a condition.

Is this the correct SE to ask this question? I'm more accustomed to stats.SE but I've never quite figured the difference between ai.SE, stats.SE and datascience.SE

Maybe you could remind us what $v$ means in this context? (since it isn't in the definition)

@bogovicj, $V$ is the set of observed variables (variables included in the model. In this case, say given $\bar{V}\subseteq V$, then I meant $P^{(1)}(\bar{V}=v)=P^{(2)}(\bar{V}=v)$, so agreement of the two probabilities on any single event.
